# SharePoint WebPart rendering at runtime

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I've been through all SharePoints posts all over the interwebs and I can't find anything to point me in the right direction.

I'm developing a web part, that should, in theory re-render the contents of web parts situated within a given zone, into itself. Lot of words, let me explain a bit more.

I have a zone, for example: MyZone that will hosts "WebPartA" and "WebPartB", and "WebPartC". WebPartC needs to hide A and B, and render their contents in itself, however, I cannot find any reference to how to accomplish this. Is this possible, and does anyone out there have an example I can look at.

I've only started SP development recently and would love to see if I can achieve something like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can modify the source of webparts A and B, you could expose the data they provide to WebPartC using Sharepoint provider/connector plumbing. Google can supply you with tons of sample code for connecting webparts.

If that's not an option, another option would be to do it all in javascript. A framework like jquery would help immensely. In a nutshell, WebPartC would need to render javascript code to...

- Grab the HTML rendered by the other webparts
- Hide the other webparts

Comment: initial investigation into how others might have achieved similar results show the use of JavaScript which I'm not 100% opposed. will fire off a search on provider plumbing.